# Why is an assignment to a base class valid, but an assignment to a derived class a compilation error?

Tags: c++, inheritance, compiler-errors

This was an interview question. Consider the following:

```
struct A {}; 
struct B : A {}; 
A a; 
B b; 
a = b;
b = a;
```

Why does `b = a;` throw an error, while `a = b;` is perfectly fine?

Comment: That’s actually a very good question. There’s no immediately obvious reason why the first statement works.

Comment: I'm assuming a struct behaves just like a class - it just chops off all the unique 'B' struct items and copies all the 'a's.

Comment: @user: a struct is a class. It's just that stuff is public by the default. Other than that they're the same.

Comment: I would probably write the question to use classes to get at the essence of understanding of inheritance.

Comment: @JohnMcG: `struct`s are `class`es in C++. There's no "essence" being obfuscated here.

Comment: Recommended reading on Name Hiding: Effective C++: Tip 33.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Because the implicitly declared copy assignment operator of `B` hides the implicitly declared copy assignment operator of `A`.

So for the line `b = a`, only the the `operator=` of `B` is a candidate. But its parameter has type `B const&`, which cannot be initialized by an `A` argument (you would need a downcast). So you get an error.

Comment: You can try changing the definition of `B` to `struct B : A { using A::operator=; };` and observe that both lines will compile.

Comment: Good answer that makes total sense. The other answers are more philosophical, while this one contains the specific technical reason that it doesn't work.

Comment: @Johannes - line 1 is an example of object-slicing. So, `a` has only it's own sub-object. Now, in line 2 to do `b = a ;` , shouldn't `a` must possess both the sub-objects of type `a`,`b` ? Though this compiles, isn't the concept flawed ? Thanks.

Comment: How does the implicitly declared copy assignment operator of B hides the implicitly declared copy assignment operator of A?

Comment: @maxpayne - http://ideone.com/HVpbq . This example should clear what @Johannes meant. Even clearer, check this - http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.9

Comment: @Johannes : Why does line 1 works? It looks obvious, but I would like to know correct technical detail about it. :)

Comment: @maxpayne Adding `using A::operator=;` to `B` will fix it, if that helps clarify

Comment: @logic_max:
    `struct A {};
    struct B {
        A& operator= (const &A) {return *this} // it was hidden
    };
    
    A a;
    B b;
`
    a = b;   b = a;   // no compilation error here

Answer (score 25):

Because every B is an A, but not every A is a B.

Edited following comments to make things a bit clearer (I modified your example):

```
struct A {int someInt;}; 
struct B : A {int anotherInt}; 
A a; 
B b; 

/* Compiler thinks: B inherits from A, so I'm going to create
   a new A from b, stripping B-specific fields. Then, I assign it to a.
   Let's do this!
 */
a = b;

/* Compiler thinks: I'm missing some information here! If I create a new B
   from a, what do I put in b.anotherInt?
   Let's not do this!
 */
b = a;
```

In your example, there's no attributes `someInt` nor `anotherInt`, so it *could* work. But the compiler will not allow it anyway.

Comment: -1: Philosophically, your answer is correct, but the philosophy only translates straightforwardly into code when you're talking using pointers to refer to the objects. There are some technical details about the implicit `A::operator=` and `B::operator=` missing that other answers cover better.

Comment: @LokiAstari: you're wrong. the answer is correct, just not very C++ technical. other languages do the same in slightly different ways. it is better to understand the "why" and not the technical C++ level details, than having memorized the details and not understand the "why". litb's answer is a bit lacking in the "why" department.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Now it is good. Without the comments it was meaningless. See history.

Answer (score 6):

It's true that a `B` is an `A`, but an `A` is not a `B`, but this fact is only directly applicable when you're working with pointers or references to `A`'s and `B`'s. The problem here is your assignment operator.

```
struct A {}; 
struct B : A {};
```

Is equivalent to

```
struct A {
   A& operator=(const A&);
}; 
struct B : A {
   B& operator=(const B&);
};
```

So when you're assigning below:

```
A a; 
B b; 
a = b;
```

The assignment operator on `a` can be called with an argument of `b`, because a `B` is an `A`, so `b` can be passed to the assignment operator as an `A&`. Note that `a`'s assignment operator only knows about the data that's in an `A`, and not the stuff in a `B`, so any members of B that aren't part of A get lost - this is known as 'slicing'.

But when you're trying to assign:

```
b = a;
```

`a` is of type `A`, which is not a `B`, so `a` can't match the `B&` parameter to `b`'s assignment operator.

You would think that `b=a` should just call the inherited `A& A::operator=(const A&)`, but this is not the case.  The assignment operator `B& B::operator=(const B&)` hides the operator that would be inherited from `A`. It can be restored again with a `using A::operator=;` declaration.

Answer (score 4):

I've changed the names of your structs to make the reason obvious:

```
struct Animal {}; 
struct Bear : Animal {}; 
Animal a; 
Bear b; 
a = b; // line 1 
b = a; // line 2
```

Clearly, any Bear is also an Animal, but not every Animal can be considered a Bear.

Because every B "isa" A, any instance of B must also be an instance of A: by definition it has the same members in the same order as any other instance of A. Copying b into a loses the B-specific members, but completely fills the members of a resulting in a struct that satisfies the requirements of A. Copying a to b, on the other hand, may leave b incomplete because B could have more members than A. That's hard to see here because neither A nor B has any members at all, but this is why the compiler allows one assignment and not the other.

Comment: This is wrong for the same reason as Cicada’s answer; see comments there for an explanation. Oh, and it’s also wrong for other reasons (LSP).

Comment: Changing the names doesn't make it any more obvious to me.

Comment: The Rectangle/Square inheritance is a classic example of where inheritance as "is-a" is counter-intuitive to some as you could argue that Rectangle should be a subclass of Square instead. Can you give a better example?

Comment: @Martin, you make a great point. How about Bear instead of Square? ;-)

Comment: Well... given `Animal::setCovering(Covering c);` you can do `Bear b; b.setCovering(Feathers);`. So you could also argue that an Animal is a Bear, or that none is a sublcass of the other. What matters is not who inherits from whom, but *what* gets inherited.

Comment: Square/Rectangle is not a bad example per se. A square *is* indeed a rectangle and behaves like one. It doesn't break LSP, as long as what you are modelling is squares and rectangles. LSP gets broken when you start to model mutable squares and mutable rectangles.

Comment: If anyone didn't understand the problem I was referring to: https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem So using Rectangle/Square in an example about inheritance isn't a good idea unless you want to discuss that exact problem.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that if there's not an explicitly declared copy-assignment operators one will be implicitly declared and defined for any class (and structs are classes in C++).

For `struct A` it'll have the following signature:

```
A& A::operator=(const A&)
```

And it simply performs memberwise assignment of its subobjects.

`a = b;` is OK because `B` will match with the `const A&` parameter for `A::operator=(const A&)`.  Since only members of `A` are 'memberwise assigned' to the target, any members of `B` that aren't part of `A` get lost - this is known as 'slicing'.

For `struct B` the implcit assignment operator will have the following signature:

```
B& B::operator=(const B&)
```

`b = a;` is not OK because `A` won't match the `const B&` argument.

Answer (score 1):

If I am getting interviewed then, I will explain in little philosophical way.

```
a = b;
```

is valid, because every `B` contains `A` as its part. So `a` can extract `A` from within `B`. However, `A` doesn't contain `B`. thus `b` cannot find `B` from within `A`; that's why,

```
b = a;
```

is invalid.

[Analogically, a `void*` can be found in any `Type*`, but `Type*` cannot be found in `void*` (thus we need a cast).]

Comment: This is **also** wrong. The first conversion is lossy (that is, it incurs a loss of information). So why is it valid? It shouldn’t be. Your analogy is flawed because the conversion to `void*` isn’t lossy.

Comment: @Konrad, I disagree. Information is lost, but the B-specific parts of the b object are not needed for the object to be a valid A, so the B-specific members can be sliced away. This *is* a debated part of the C++ standard because it cause problems with non-virtual functions. For plain data objects, there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Martin Even plain data objects will suffer from this loss; consider the (allowed) implicit conversion from `double` to `int`. The fact that C++ allows this is inane. Most modern languages forbid this because it’s dangerous.

Comment: @Konrad, when we do `a = b;`, the loss is expected. That's why it's slicing. The analogy is just to support the natural conversion.

Comment: @Konrad The question was not about conversion between numeric types.

Comment: @iammilind You can’t know when or if the loss is expected. In general, it isn’t. That’s why explicit conversions exist. They would be completely useless if the side-effect were always expected. In fact, we could just bin the whole strong typing if we always expected conversions.

Comment: @MartinVilcans Wrong. It was about types in general, and yes, this *includes numeric types*. In particular, you can also implement numeric types (e.g. `complex` or `bigint`) in custom types. Furthermore, the reasoning is entirely analogous. Your assertion that “it shouldn’t be a problem” is simply wrong in general, and I’ve shown you a counter-example.

Comment: @Konrad, read the question again. It was specifically about subclassing of structs. Neither of int and double is a subclass of the other.

Comment: @Martin You are shifting the goalpost, and that’s dishonest. Now you say that the question isn’t about `int` and `double` – and I agree, though the analogy is still valid. But before you said that the question isn’t about numeric types and that’s just wrong. Structures can also be numeric types (again, see my example of `complex`). I have already said all of this.

Comment: @Konrad, this is not the place for a lengthy discussion, even though it's interesting. Can you write a programmers.SE question, a blog post or something about this? I see a big difference between int/double (which are unrelated types) and A/B (where B is a subclass of A).